# ConstraintLayout no longer fills gap with second view when first view is constrained with layout_constraintDimensionRatio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I ran into a problem when designing a fragment with a `ConstraintLayout`. I want two views inside the fragment stacked on top of each other, with the top view constrained to a ratio of 4:3 and the bottom one filling the rest of the available space. So I created the following layout, expecting the desired behavior:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_top" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

However, this layout does not produce the desired effect but instead leaves gaps between the views and on the top and bottom of the whole layout:

[image: Undesired gaps in the layout]

Why is the ratio being applied to both views? Is there a way to circumvent that behavior and have only the top view restricted to the 4:3 ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I actually found the solution I am looking for. Since the height of `view_top` is already given through the ratio there is no need for the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_bottom"`-constraint. By simply removing it the desired behavior is reached and the views look like this, without any gaps:

[image]